# Sum with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of labels as shown on a page. I want to sum the values and store them in  `final_cpa`.

**HTML :**

```
<label class="tmpcpa">32.1</label>
```

**JS :**

```
function calculate_final_cpa() {
        var final_cpa = 0;
        var allfilled = false;
        $('.tmpcpa').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != 0) {
            final_cpa += parseInt($(this).text()) || 0;
            allfilled = true;
            } else {
                allfilled = false;
            }
        });
             console.log(final_cpa); 
             console.log(allfilled);
    }

    var run = setInterval(calculate_final_cpa, 500);
```

However  `final_cpa` is  always 0 and  `allfilled` remains `false`.

Comment: Because `($(this).val() != 0)` never passes.

Comment: Please read documentation before posting. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: note that **parseInt** removes every decimal; value behind the dots. Use **parseFloat** instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That because label don't have a `value` attribute so the `.val()` function will always return an empty string, you have to use `.text()` instead to get the text content inside the label element :

```
if ($(this).val() != 0) {
```

Should be :

```
if ($(this).text() != 0) {
```

**NOTE :** as *Rayon* mentioned in the comment below `text()` will always return `string` so better to change the zero in condition to string `'0'`.

Hope this helps.

```js
function calculate_final_cpa() {
  var final_cpa = 0;
  var allfilled = false;

  $('.tmpcpa').each(function () { 
    if ($(this).text() != '0') {
      final_cpa += parseInt($(this).text()) || 0;
      allfilled = true;
    } else {
      allfilled = false;
    }
  });
  console.log(final_cpa); 
  console.log(allfilled);
}

calculate_final_cpa();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="tmpcpa">32.1</label>
```

Comment: @Rayon thanks for your intervention, since the OP use `!= 0` in the condition that will work just fine instead `!== 0` will pass a zero value.. anyway updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check `$(this).text() != ""` instead of `$(this).val() != 0` as You can not use `.val()` for getting label text. `.text(`) will give you text of label

```
if ($(this).text() != "" && $(this).text() != "0") { 
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you need to use `.text()` instead of `.val()` to get the text inside a label. Also, if you are expecting your result to contain decimal digits, you need to use `parseFloat()`:

```js
function calculate_final_cpa() {
        var final_cpa = 0;
        var allfilled = false;
        $('.tmpcpa').each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() != 0) {
            final_cpa += parseFloat($(this).text()) || 0;
            allfilled = true;
            } else {
                allfilled = false;
            }
        });
        console.log(final_cpa); 
        console.log(allfilled);
}

calculate_final_cpa();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="tmpcpa">32.1</label>
<br />
<label class="tmpcpa">32.1</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
if ($(this).val() != 0)
```

**to**

```
if (parseInt($(this).text()) != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside your code had an error, you should check the content of the table before parsing them. And because you use decimals in your example, you should switch from `parseInt` to `parseFloat` too.

And your `allfilled` varibale makes no sense, because if the last element of `.tmpcpa` was empty, it will be false again. So i removed it.

```
function calculate_final_cpa() {
    var final_cpa = 0;

    $('.tmpcpa').each(function () {
        var content = $(this).text();
        final_cpa += IsNumeric(content) ? parseFloat(content) : 0;
    });

    console.log(final_cpa); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Test it with `.text` instead of `val()` as `label` has no `value` property
- Use `Unary plus(+)/Number` operator instead of `parseInt` as `parseInt` will ignore `floating` point
- Use `length` of `lable-elements` to test whether all the label has values `!== 0`

```js
function calculate_final_cpa() {
  var final_cpa = 0;
  var countOfFilled = 0;
  $('.tmpcpa').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() !== '0') {
      final_cpa += +($(this).text()) || 0;
      ++countOfFilled;
    }
  });
  console.log('Total:  ' + final_cpa);
  console.log('All filled  ' + $('.tmpcpa').length === countOfFilled);
}

calculate_final_cpa();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="tmpcpa">32.1</label>
<label class="tmpcpa">32.1</label>
<label class="tmpcpa">0</label>
```